# Ошибка компиляции файла APK в unity

Tags: apk, unity3d-android, jdk11

Как я понял проблема в **JDK**

Сама ошибка:

```
    CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to build apk.
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/Android/android-sdk\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -

stderr[
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at SDKMain.main(SDKMain.java:130)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/BASE64Encoder
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.build.SignedJarBuilder.<init>(SignedJarBuilder.java:177)
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.init(ApkBuilder.java:446)
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.<init>(ApkBuilder.java:422)
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.<init>(ApkBuilder.java:362)
    at UnityApkBuilder.<init>(UnityApkBuilder.java:214)
    at UnityApkBuilder.main(UnityApkBuilder.java:34)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.BASE64Encoder
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:436)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 11 more
]
stdout[

]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandInternal (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandSafe (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изменил версию Java, и все заработало

Comment: На какую версию?

Comment: Unity3d вроде как выше восьмого jdk не поддерживает.

Comment: На семёрку, была 12